# If dim(V) + dim(W) > dim(R^n), show that some nonzero vector is in V & W. [GStrang P183, 3.5.45]

Tags: linear-algebra

> Inside $\mathbb{R^n}$, suppose dimension$(\mathbf{V})$ + dimension$(\mathbf{W}) > n$.    Show that some nonzero vector is in both $\mathbf{V}$ and $\mathbf{W}$.

**Answer :** Since $\dim\mathbf{V} + \dim\mathbf{W} = \dim\mathbf{(V \cap W)} + \dim(\mathbf{V + W}) \quad> n$,
 $\Large{\color{red}{[}}$ thus $\dim\mathbf{(V \cap W)} > 0$ $\Large{{\color{red}{]}}}$. So $V \cap W$ contains nonzero vectors. $\quad \square$

$\Large{1.}$ This question doesn't specify what are $\mathbf{V}, \mathbf{W}$. Why not? Should they be subspaces?

$\Large{2.}$ How and why does the red bracket follow? $\dim(\mathbf{V + W})$ is unknown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "inside $\mathbb{R}^n$" implies that $V$ and $W$ are subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$; in particular, since we're referring to dimension, it must be assumed that $V$ and $W$ are vector subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Given this assumption, we see that $V + W \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ so that $\dim(V + W) \le n$. But since

$$n < \dim(V \cap W) + \dim(V + W) \le \dim(V \cap W) + n$$

In particular, $\dim(V \cap W)$ can't be zero, or the right side is too small.